# Calculate daily use from running total in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have an sql-table with the following columns and I am trying to find a way to automatically calculate the daily usage for each entry.  'Total Usage' is a running total and there is an entry once per day per person.

Ultimately I want be able to manipulate it as a list in c# but an sql-query based method would be useful as well.  This is easy to do in excel but I was hoping for a way to automate it....

```
Date  |  Name  |  Total Usage | Daily Usage

2016-01-01 | John | 60 | ?
2016-01-02 | John | 63 | ?
2016-01-03 | John | 66 | ?
2016-01-01 | Jane | 30 | ?
2016-01-02 | Jane | 50 | ?
2016-01-03 | Jane | 75 | ?
```

Comment: If you can get the table as some sort of List, you use LINQ with something like `table.Select(row => row.Column[2] / 365)` or `from row in table select row.Column[2] / 365`

Comment: For the data given in your question, what is the 'Total Usage' value?

Comment: It's total water usage

Comment: You want daily usage for each person for each day by summing 'Total Usage' value for each person?

Answer (score 0):

Pertinent to your question, you can get the result table using following code snippet written in C#, which utilizes `System.Data` and `System.Data.SqlClient` object Library:

```
strSQL = "Select [Name], AVG([Total Usage]) As AvrUsage FROM [YourTableName] GROUP BY [Name]";
               // get data table with two columns: Name and AvgUsage
                using (SqlConnection _connSql = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand _commandSql = new (SqlCommand())
                    {
                        _commandSql.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        _commandSql.Connection = _connSql;
                        _commandSql.CommandText = strSQL;
                        _connSql.Open();

                        using (SqlDataReader _drSql = _commandSql.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
                            _dt.Load(_drSql);
                            return _dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw; 
            }
```

, where `connString` - is a connection string to your Sql Database.

Alternatively, instead of `AVG([Total Usage])` you can apply `SUM([Total Usage])/365`, depends on your particular requirement definitions.

Hope this may help.